# How to execute like search in SQL Server which involves Square Brackets

Tags: sql-server

```
select * from Answers where AnswerName like '%No [DETAILS REQUIRED]%'
```

The above-given query does not return any results while there is an entry in the column "AnswerName " with the exact text as "No [DETAILS REQUIRED]"

Answer (score 2):

you can use an `escape` character:

```
select * from Answers where AnswerName like '%No \[DETAILS REQUIRED\]%' escape '\'
```

Answer (score 0):

use escape character

```
match_expression [ NOT ] LIKE pattern [ ESCAPE escape_character ]  

select * 
from Answers 
where AnswerName like '%No @[DETAILS REQUIRED@]%' ESCAPE '@'
```